# Restrict Folder Access in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, authorization, hdfs

Two different groups of people plan to use our hadoop cluster, but I don't want them to see each other's data.

How can I prevent this functionality on hadoop cluster ?

I understand that if you set a environment variable you can easily impersonate the hadoop superuser and access all data in HDFS. Is there an simpler way to prevent this or kerberos and ldap based security is the only way to go?

Comment: Just curious, how can you impersonate hadoop superuser?

Answer (score 0):

**Kerberos is the only way to prevent users in Hadoop from impersonating** as `hdfs` superuser and misusing privileges.

Its very simple for users to impersonate as hdfs user (who happens to be the superuser of hadoop in most distributions). Anyone could do that by specifying the env variable `HADOOP_USER_NAME` to `hdfs`.

Comment: Is it possible that we don't allow normal users to set the Environment variable in the Linux environment and avoid them as acting to as superuser in hdfs ?